# Web Articles/Comments Counts

Tags: sql, select, web, max, average

How do I list the top 10 articles that, on average, have the most comments to them when a page view occurs.

```
SELECT  TOP 10 a.title as 'articles'
FROM    articles a 
JOIN    website_pageviews b on a.id = b.article_id
JOIN    comments c on a.id = c.commented_article_id 
GROUP BY a.id
```

I've gotten this far but i'm a little lost now - how do i do the "on average" part.

my tables are as follows

```
table: website_pageviews (timestamp, article_id, visitor_id, and a bunch of others)
table: articles (id, title, timestamp, content, author, subject)
table: comments (commented_article_id, user_id, timestamp, text)
```

where do i use the max, or average?
please help ... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  TOP 10 a.title as articles,
        count(c.commented_article_id) * 100 / count(b.visitor_id) as percentage
FROM    articles a 
JOIN    website_pageviews b on a.id = b.article_id
JOIN    comments c on a.id = c.commented_article_id 
GROUP BY a.id, a.title
order by count(c.commented_article_id) * 100 / count(b.visitor_id) desc
```

Comment: Using 'order' by is enough? I don't need a nested select? or anything more complex?

Comment: This is how you get al list of articles that have the most comments. Or what do you mean by *average*?

Comment: The question asks 'How do I list the top 10 articles that, **on average**, have the most comments to them when a page view occurs. I'm not 100% sure what it means.

Comment: You asked the question. If anybody knows what it means, then it's you.

Comment: Touche. Sadly I wish that was the case :-) but I think that this is what is asked of me. Thank for your help.

Comment: if i were to adjust the query above to list the top ten articles. in terms of percent of articles reads which resulted in a comment being written. In other words they have higher odds that a reader will read that comment. Do i simply change the order by?

Comment: Yes. I updated the answer. It may be what you are looking for.